# JavaScript - Submitting to database after checking

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, validation, xhtml

I have made some validation so it checks if a text field is an email address. My next task is when the input is correct it sends it to my php file which sends the data to the database.

Any ideas?

```
  JS: <script>
   function validateForm() {
var x = document.forms["reg"]["User"].value;
var letters = "@";
if (x.match(letters))
{
  alert("Can't Have Email Address As USERNAME!");
} 


   }


       </script>
```

XHTML part:

```
<form name="reg" action="Register.html" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
```

So when the text field doesn't contain a "@" I want the data to be sent to (DB.php).

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: You need to change your `action` attribute: `action="DB.php"`

Comment: Fyi, ALWAYS validate on server side, in addition to any client side validation you do.

Comment: @jeroen when I do that it validates correctly but still inserts into the DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change 2 things:

1. You need to change your `action` attribute so that the form posts to the correct script: `action="DB.php"`
2. You need to return a boolean value from your javascript function; when `false` is returned the form submit will be cancelled:

   `function validateForm() {
     var x = document.forms["reg"]["User"].value;
     var letters = "@";
     if (x.match(letters)) {
       alert("Can't Have Email Address As USERNAME!");
       return false;
     }
     return true;
   }`

Answer (score 0):

Your action attribute needs to be pointed at the desired PHP file name.

```
<form name="reg" action="DB.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
```

You also need to `return false` in your javascript if you dont want to submit the form as that will override the default event